# How difficult is it for ISPs to understand a user is using VPN?

Tags: vpn, government

If a user is using VPN, how difficult is it for an ISP to know that a user is using VPN ? If the government demands, isn't it possible for the ISP to provide a list of customers who could be using VPN by making a list of customers who are always hitting a single IP (as the user always connects to the same VPN network) ? My questions may be naive & hypothetical, but I'm curious to understand if there is anything stopping the ISPs from doing it.

If the government knows we are using a VPN, won't it get more attention from them ? I'm only theoretically curious to know why people keep saying using VPN is more secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how difficult is it for an ISP to know that a user is using VPN

Actual implementations of VPN vary and don't always mean that the user always hits the same IP address. But still an ISP or anybody else having access to their infrastructure could detect atypical traffic patterns (like nearly no web access but lots of other traffic) and thus conclude the use of VPN or other techniques to hide the real traffic.

> favorite
>   If a user is using VPN, how difficult is it for an ISP to know that a user is using VPN ? If the government demands, isn't it possible for the ISP to provide a list of customers who could be using VPN by making a list of customers who are always hitting a single IP (as the user always connects to the same VPN network) ? My questions may be naive & hypothetical, but I'm curious to understand if there is anything stopping the ISPs from doing it.
>
> If the government knows we are using a VPN, won't it get more attention from them.

Depending where you live this might happen.

> people keep saying using VPN is more secure

VPN makes the data transport itself more secure by encrypting the communication and this way protects against sniffing by a man in the middle. Depending on how suspicious your are this might lead to an increased risk of getting hacked directly in order to get access to the data before encryption. Or in cases where encryption is forbidden by law it might increase the risk of getting arrested.